# Struggling to get ordered results from the last retrieved article, given array of elements to search in

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collections of objects with structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5233a700bc7b9f31580a9de0"),
    "id" : "3df7ce4cc2586c37607a8266093617da",
    "published_at" : ISODate("2013-09-13T23:59:59Z"),
    ...
    "topic_id" : [
        284,
        9741
    ],
    ...
    "date" : NumberLong("1379116800055")
}
```

I'm trying to use the following query:

```
db.collection.find({"topic_id": { $in: [ 9723, 9953, 9558, 9982, 9833, 301, ... 9356, 9990, 9497, 9724] }, "date": { $gte: 1378944001000, $lte: 1378954799000 }, "_id": { $gt: ObjectId('523104ddbc7b9f023700193c') }}).sort({ "_id": 1 }).limit(1000)
```

The above query uses `topic_id, date` index but then it does not keep the order of returned results.

Forcing it to use `hint({_id:1})` makes the results ordered, but the `nscanned` is 1 million documents even though `limit(1000)` is specified.

What am I missing?